# PhD student who should be the correpsonding author

Tags: publications, phd, journals, paper-submission

I am a PhD student, should I put my supervisor as the corresponding author, will this increase my chance of publication?

Comment: I'm assuming your advisor is actually an author. Yes?

Comment: Are you asking because you want to obtain knowledge or because you are really in this Situation?

Comment: If the latter, did you ask the supervisor if he wants to be corres.  author?